# How to Find The User Who Stopped Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-container

I want to know what is the user who stopped a docker container.

There are several user accounts on my server. I suspect that one of them sometimes stops the container.

How can I find the user that performed this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `su -c history username` to check command history of a user, I don't know how many users you have but you could loop through them and grep for commands taking docker containers down.

Comment: The user who wants to execute this query is not root

Comment: Try sudo cat /home/USER_YOU_WANT_TO_VIEW/.bash_history then

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton If the user is not **root** how s/he can execute **sudo** command?

Comment: Being logged in as root and having sudo permissions aren't the same thing. By asking this question I made the assumption that they have sudo permissions to read other users history, otherwise the question makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can install `GNU Accounting Utilities`, to be able to see commands executed by users:

```
#centos
yum install psacct
# ubuntu: 
apt-get install acct

#Also make sure that the cooresponding service is enabled: 
/etc/init.d/psacct status
```

Then, after you realize that the container is stopped execute:

```
lastcomm --command docker
# or
lastcomm --command kill
```

to see which executed the above command(s).

You can use the above in combination with:

```
 docker container logs <name-of-the-container>
```

to see what is the exact time on which the container was stopped. (E.g. you may see a message on the logs: "stopping service..") and match it with `lastcomm` output.

Other useful commands that come with the above package:`sa`, `ac`